# Vertically align image with caption in div

Tags: html, css

I am trying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div) (first answer) to vertically align an image over a div that has the following additional css properties so it takes the whole space:

```
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
```

The problem is, even with the fiddle referenced in the original question ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4RPFa/74/)), if you add an additional span with a text, separated by a `<br/>`, this `span` shows outside of the containing div.

I want to align both the image and caption *inside* the div.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Splash screen</title>
<style>
.frame {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
        text-align: center; 
}
.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 25px;
    max-width: 160px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="frame">
    <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="center" src="img/splash/splash.png" />
      <br />
      HELLO WORLD
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adjust with `<br />`, you'll have to change `height` to `min-height`

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RPFa/2200/)

and this is your css :

```
frame {
    min-height: 25px;      /* equals max image height */
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center; margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Also, in your example fiddle, class is assigned wrong way :

`<div class=frame>`

this is wrong

```
<div class="frame">
      /*___^_____^ see the quotes */
```

**EDIT**

In you case...keep `span` `inline` and set `position:relative`

```
span.helper {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
```

[**wroking demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5wr3/3/)

**EDIT 2**

Use `display:table` to achieve your purpose rather than `position`.

**Note** CSS table is IE8= compatible!!

[<kbd>**working fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/g5wr3/5/)

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.frame {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
.helper {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 25px;
    max-width: 160px;
}
```

Comment: I can't change the height, as I posted my div needs to stretch both on width and height to the size of the window, so I use a `position: absolute` and fix all positions to zero.

Comment: @MichelReap : can you give me your fiddle...not the reference one....that will help draft custom solution for you!! :)

Comment: the problem is, that does not center vertically

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45707/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-michelreap)